# Eclipse compiler options - How can I set the debug level

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction

I was wondering how you can set the debug level when building a java source file or project in the Eclipse IDE? The way I would do it manually with java would be

```
javac -g Foo.java
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the debug output by selecting the **Properties** menu entry when rightclicking your project in the Package Explorer view and selection the **Java Compiler** entry in the dialog.

[image: Debug Settings]