# Lline numbers missing in google play crash stack trace

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play, stack-trace

I recently moved some code to a library project. Since then, when a crash happens in that library, the stack trace of the crash report doesn't show the line number in the library's code - **Unknown Source** is shown instead.

The problem is quite obvious - hard to fix an NPE if I don't know in where it happened.

Example:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at library.SomeClass2.b(Unknown Source)
at library.SomeClass1.a(Unknown Source)
at android.app.SomeClass.a(SomeClass.java:239)
...
```

*** Note that the library project is a regular Java project - referenced from the Android project (No hanky-panky - simple eclipse java project dependency).

Comment: are you using proguard?

Comment: @user2944616 - I see a proguard.cfg file in the Android project. It was generated long time ago when I first created the project. Why do you ask?

Comment: I saw that sometimes tha infromation was not complete when I used proguard.

Comment: @user2944616 - I guess there was a reason for the proguard file to be generated. Anyhow, I couldn't find anything on the web regarding missing line numbers info on Android crash reports - nor any connection to the proguard file.

Comment: I removed the proguard file (proguard.cfg) completely. The apk is 6.6MB instead of 6.4MB. Small difference IMO. I'll update on the results.

Comment: I deleted the proguard file completely and still see no line numbers - shows `<package>.<class>.<method>(Unknown Source)`. I tested it by publishing an alpha version that throws exception in a library file.

Comment: You might be able to edit your proguard settings to get it to keep line numbers.

Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861986/how-do-you-interpret-a-deobfuscated-android-crash-report

Comment: @ktusznio - the line numbers are shown for my android project classes but not for the java library classes. Proguard seems to be configured ok.

Comment: Check the compiler settings for your library project, it should be configured to generate debug information for the compiled class files.

Comment: @iddo - what "compiler settings"?

Comment: These ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634525/eclipse-compiler-options-how-can-i-set-the-debug-level

Comment: @iddo - all checkboxes checked. Eventually it's built by Android's build mechanism - ant. The build looks at the .classpath but don't know if it looks at all the params of the Eclipse project.